# Comparing a time value with a value in ssis

Tags: t-sql, ssis

I would like to use such an expression in dereived column, but it remains red (it is not accepted):

```
(DT_DBTIME) [Datum]  =="00:00:00" ? 1 : 2
```

(if time part of variable [Datum] = "00:00:00" then 1 else 2)

Comment: CASE CAST([Datum] AS TIME) WHEN '00:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

Comment: thanks but this one doesnt work in ssis derived column expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compare DT_DBTIME and DT_WSTR type. Try to cast data from DT_WSTR to DT_DBTIME type:

```
(DT_DBTIME) [Datum]  == (DT_DBTIME)"00:00:00" ? 1 : 2
```